# Cordova Scandit not working

Tags: android, cordova, barcode-scanner

Followed the steps given in the link below:

https://github.com/Scandit/BarcodeScannerPlugin

and added the following to the config.xml

```
<feature name="ScanditSDK"> <param name="android-package" value="com.mirasense.scanditsdk.plugin.ScanditSDK"/> </feature>
```

Tested the app using Phonegap Desktop, when I click the "Scan" button, nothing happens. What have I missed? Your help please. Thanks

Comment: did you run the sample code provided?

Comment: do mention your OS version and device you are using

Comment: Hi, Thank you for replying. Yes, I was trying the sample code given in the following link https://github.com/Scandit/BarcodeScannerPlugin. The test was done on Nexus 4 running KitKat 4.4.4. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include all these files into your android project.

https://github.com/Scandit/BarcodeScannerPlugin/tree/master/src/android/com/mirasense/scanditsdk/plugin